# Google Plus integration in Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 Store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, google-plus

Is there any sdk available to integrate the google plus in windows phone 8 and windows 8 store app?
Like the facebook sdk is available which makes our life easy to integrate the facebook in our app.
I want sdk which will make my life easy to integrate the google  plus with windows 8.

Or

any other solution to integrate google plus with my windows 8 apps.

Thank You.

Comment: _What you have tried so far? Show us your efforts_

Comment: have you looked at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gus Class](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GusClass/) on the Google+ Developer Relations team has done some work around Windows 8 and the .NET client library to show how to do some level of integration with Windows 8. The following is one example of how to authenticate a user and get Google+ data:

http://gusclass.com/blog/2012/11/20/pulling-google-data-into-windows-store-apps/